# I get an error when running the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, echo, ubuntu-16.04

So I've built an image with `docker build -t myimage2:1.0 .`

This is my Dockerfile:

```
#getting base image
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER gilebrt <email@bla.com>

RUN apt-get update

CMD ["echo", "Hello World"]
```

But when running `docker run myimage2:1.0`, I get the error below

> /bin/sh: 1: [“echo”,”Hello: not found

I tried changing the CMD line, among other things to: `CMD "echo hello World"`, but I still get the error:

> /bin/sh: 1: echo hello World: not found

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS`
I am sure it's something silly, but I can't find the issue...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, the [`MAINTAINER` instruction is deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated) and should be replaced with something like `LABEL maintainer="..."`.

Comment: Could you please paste your entire Dockerfile as it is on your system, as I can't replicate the issue you're having.

Please let us know the version of Docker you're using as well.

Comment: I was able to run this Dockerfile fine. There was no error and `docker run --rm myimage2` (where `myimage2` is the image built using the above Dockerfile) outputs `Hello World` as expected.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying. @FrankLouwers That is my whole Dockerfile (I am just starting to use docker), and the issue was solved by what Alex Pliutau suggested in the answers.

Comment: @thushv89 yes, I am actually following a tutorial online and for the guy making the tutorial it also worked fine. But for me it didn't (as explained in the question). I managed to make it work by changing to ```CMD ["echo", "\"Hello World\""]``` (as Alex Pliutau suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap "Hello World" with quotes, otherwise it will execute as `echo Hello World`, which is not valid, it should be `echo "Hello World"`.

```
#getting base image
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER gilebrt <email@bla.com>

RUN apt-get update

CMD ["echo", "\"Hello World\""]
```

Comment: Why `echo Hello World` is not valid?

Answer (score 2):

CMD ["echo", "Hello World"] would do.